# Secondary axis in percentage ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

Can someone please help me to add the secondary axis in percentage, please? I've tried different approaches, but haven't been able to get any results.

I'll provide the data bellow:

```r
year <- c("2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020")
sex <- c("male","male","male","male","male","male","male","male","male","male","male","female","female","female","female","female","female","female","female","female","female","female")
number <- c(12,5,15,5,4,6,5,5,8,4,0,54,64,70,50,54,35,40,37,42,36,24)
perFailed <- c(0.090909091,0.057971014,0.117647059,0.163636364,0.068965517,0.048780488,0.044444444,0.071428571, 0.1,0.1,0)
data <- data.frame(year,sex,number,perFailed)
data$year <- as.factor(data$year)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=year, y=number, fill=sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  theme_bw()
```

I don't know how, but R duplicated my last column (`perFailed`).
This data needs to be plotted as `geom_line()` on the secondary axis.

Thank you, everyone.

[image: plot]

Comment: What did you try? The use of `ggplot2::sec_axis` is straight-forward once you realize that it is 100% cosmetic, no data is changed or otherwise accommodated with it.

Comment: FYI, your code is broken: you define `year` and use `Year`. Please *test* code you give us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```r
ratio <- max(data$number) / max(data$perFailed)
data <- transform(data, perFailedScaled = perFailed * ratio)
head(data)
#   year  sex number  perFailed Year perFailedScaled
# 1 2010 male     12 0.09090909 2010        38.88889
# 2 2011 male      5 0.05797101 2011        24.79871
# 3 2012 male     15 0.11764706 2012        50.32680
# 4 2013 male      5 0.16363636 2013        70.00000
# 5 2014 male      4 0.06896552 2014        29.50192
# 6 2015 male      6 0.04878049 2015        20.86721

ggplot(data=data, aes(x=year, y=number, fill=sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_line(aes(x = match(year, sort(unique(year))), y = perFailedScaled), 
            data = ~ subset(., sex == "male")) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / ratio, labels = scales::label_percent())) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: ggplot2 barplot with line overlaid]

Notes:

1. I assume that since your numbers are invariant between `"male"` and `"female"`, that reducing the data to just one of them is okay. Without the reduction, the line is double-printed, and while that's rarely impactful nor even noticed, it seems unnecessary.
2. The use of `match(year, sort(unique(year)))` is a bit of a hack. Overlaying axes can be a little problematic, this is one way that works.

Comment: Thaanks for your promt answer. Thne percentages are related to overall failed.  Since females are predominant in my dataset, i skipped to put the annual sum of all cases,  but ploted % of failed amog all cases.  That is why I explained that R automatically doubled my entries for the variable.